# WCF дуплексный канал

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, клиент-сервер

Добрый день, решил реализовать возможность работы WCF сервиса по дуплексному каналу, но столкнулся с проблемой реализации канала на клиенте, то есть во всех прочтенных примерах не могу понять от куда берется класс реализующий InstanceContext, ни где о нем не упоминается кроме кода ,вот примеры:

> http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/a-simple-duplex-service-in-wcf/
>   -- Класс Service1Client
>
> http://wcftutorial.net/how-to-create-callback-service-in-wcf.aspx -
>   Класс MyServiceClient
>
> [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx-Класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx-%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81)
>   CalculatorDuplexClient

Помогите разобраться в реализации на клиенте

Answer (score 2):

Вам этот класс надо написать самому. Вам же не надо, чтобы обратные вызовы от сервера получал какой-то чужой класс, вам надо самому их получить? Вот и реализуйте CallbackContract самостоятельно.